# Changing a view in single page Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view

I'm very new to Angular and have built a very basic site to host some of my art on. At the moment I have an HTML page (homepage) with an `<a ng-href>` which, when clicked, loads another HTML page with all my work on it. So I have two HTML pages which means things have to load twice on my site. This is not very practical.

This is the HTML on my homepage. The `<a ng-href>` is contained inside of the custom directive `<front-page>`:

```
<div ng-controller="artCtrl" class="content">

  <front-page info="image_1"></front-page>

</div>
```

`<front-page>` directive:

```
<a ng-href="work.html">
 <img ng-src="{{ info.images }}" alt="Image not found" width="40%" height="40%">
</a>
```

The content on the second HTML page is also inside of a custom directive which looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in info">
 <img class="image" ng-src="{{ x.image }}"></img>
 <p class="name">{{ x.name }}</p>
<div>
```

I want to be able to `ng-click` on the `<a ng-href>` on the homepage and render the HTML in the directive on my second page, all on the same page (so, without loading a whole other page). 
But I have no idea what the best way to do this would be. Routing seems a bit unnecessary for such a simple site and I'm not sure if using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` would be suited for this.

Please let me know if you're confused by this question, I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

There is one more option for routing availabe in angular http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki